# factor level in R not displayed as numeric

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a data.frame with 2 million rows. One of the column is an alphanumeric Id which is repeated in that column with a unique count of 300000?

```
>head(df$ID)
    ID 
AB00153232de 
AB00153232de    
AB00153232de 
AB00155532gh 
AB00155532gh 
AB00158932ij

>df$ID<-factor(df$ID)
```

When I try to print that factor variable I get something like this:

```
>df$ID
[1] AB00153232de AB00153232de AB00153232de AB00155532gh AB00155532gh AB00158932ij 
320668 Levels: AB00153232de AB00155532gh AB00158932ij.....
```

Is the factor not being stored as a numeric vector and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `unclass` on the factor variable. It keeps the factor levels as attribute of the new variable, so that if you need it in future, you can make use of it.

```
df1$ID
#     [1] AB00153232de AB00153232de AB00153232de AB00155532gh AB00155532gh AB00158932ij
# Levels: AB00153232de AB00155532gh AB00158932ij

unclass(df1$ID)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "AB00153232de" "AB00155532gh" "AB00158932ij"
```

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), 
                                     .Label = c("AB00153232de", "AB00155532gh", "AB00158932ij"), class = "factor")), 
                 .Names = "ID", row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can I use these levels as indexes in a vector or array?

Comment: If you want just the levels after doing `unclass`, try this: `attributes(unclass(df1$ID))$levels`

Comment: I have a data.frame with two such factor variables from which I am creating a two dimensional array(matrix). My question is if I try to access a matrix element M["factor1","factor2"] will R internally search it through the numeric levels or it does the search through the character values? In 2nd case I might have to write additional logic to search through numeric values as an optimization step.

Comment: yes, under the hood factor variables are treated as integers and levels are used as labels. The levels can be used to subset a matrix or data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as.integer(df$ID)` instead.

Example:

```
R> ex <- as.factor(LETTERS)
R> ex
 [1] A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
R> str(ex)
 Factor w/ 26 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
R> as.integer(ex)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
R>
```